# Translate the header and footer text in a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I will make a lot of views, and they have to be translated (not the result of the views but the  text before / after the result of the request), how can I do ?

Is there a way to attach a node before / after (node that will be translated and shown according to the user's language)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you fix the title of the question and provide more details about your issue?!

Comment: Why don't you move your question to: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/  It's Drupal oriented, there should be more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `node N` which will hold the text that should be displayed in your view(Lets call it `view A`). Create translations for the `node N`, in all the languages that you care about.

Create a `view B` that will fetch the translated node for a given node id(`node id of N`) you can use current language filter. Now embed that `view B`, in your first view `view A` in the header region using embed view option.